# Is there a way to tell if a Drawable associated with an ImageView is Vectorial?

Tags: android

I am writing a library that changes elements on runtime - I need to know if a view is holding a Vectorial asset - anyone knows of a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the `Drawable` with `imagView.getDrawable()` and check if it is an instance of `android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable`